# how can i get a batch file to add to itself

Tags: batch-file

I have tried many different times and combinations to this but it wont work i am trying to create an operating system with a batch file (just for fun not to use) and i cant get the :createprofile section to add to the batch file it is in but it erases everything in the files coding and only adds the one bottom thing.  Here is what I've tried

```
echo (text from above entered in) > xyz.bat
echo (text...) >> xyz.bat
```

xyz.bat being the file itself

Comment: i did not mean to type but at end of second row

Comment: are you sure, you want to write to two different files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revised code:

```
echo (text from above entered in) >> xyz.bat
echo (text...) >> xy.bat
```

notice the double parentheses above.

Hope that helped! (if it didn't edit your question to include a more substantial part of your code)